# Using JAX with NetworkX

Tags: networkx, jax

Can I use JIT from JAX with NetworkX algorithms? For instance, if were to compute the average clustering coefficient for a NetworkX graph object, is it possible to use the @jit decorator to speed up my analysis pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, JAX's JIT and other transforms only work with functions implemented via JAX primitives (generally operations defined in `jax.lax`, `jax.numpy`, and related submodules). They cannot be used to compile/transform arbitrary Python code.